# Curve Deform prob

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

Taking a mesh from a existing object, apply transform, set origin to geo, or 3d cursor ,convert to curve, and the 90 angles are broken

Comment: Can you share your blend file?

Comment: Maybe at the top of the Object Data panel, under Shape, switch from 3D to 2D?

Answer (score 2):

If you set at least the path-curve to **2D** in its 'Data' tab > 'Shape' panel, then mitred corners are unambiguous, and Blender can calculate them to give even thickness at other points on the curve.

[image]